# Parsing Json array from webservice to android

Tags: java, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to parse this json data from web service to android using volley.
This is the json array to be parsed.

```
[
 {
    "id":"1",
    "conf_room_name":"Tadoba"
 },
 {
    "id":"2",
    "conf_room_name":"Melghat"
 },
 {
    "id":"3",
    "conf_room_name":"Ranthambore"
 },
 {
    "id":"4",
    "conf_room_name":"Corbett"
 },
 {
    "id":"5",
    "conf_room_name":"Pench"
 }
]
[
 {
    "id":"1",
    "area":"Mafatlal"
 },
 {
    "id":"2",
    "area":"Andheri"
 }
]
[
 {
    "id":"1",
    "type":"Is Personal"
 },
 {
    "id":"2",
    "type":"Meeting"
 }
]
```

I am using this code to get the value out of my json array object ot different arraylists.

RequestQueue requestQueue2= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
       // RequestQueue requestQueue3= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

```
    //  Create json array request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://170.241.241.198/test.php",new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
        public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray){


            for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    stringArray_conf.add(jsonObject.getString("conf_room_name"));
                    stringArray_area.add(jsonObject.getString("area"));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e("Error", "Unable to parse json array");
        }
    });

    requestQueue2.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Only 1st array is being filled properly not the other one. I get outofboundsindex exception whenever i try using values from my 2nd arraylist.

All this happens on a button click only i want this to happen when i load my page.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: add your json data instead of image

Comment: Also add the code you are using to parse the data and the java pojo you have used.

Comment: Is this okay? do you need logcat data as well? @shamimreza

Comment: Is this okay? do you need logcat data as well? @ArpitRatan

Comment: Invalid json formate.

Comment: Your JSON content consists of multiple JSON root elements.

Comment: So how do i correct it?@AnandBarnwal

Comment: second option suggested by Tran Hieu seems to be the best one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make JSON as Array as below:

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "conf_room_name": "Tadoba"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "conf_room_name": "Melghat"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "conf_room_name": "Ranthambore"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "conf_room_name": "Corbett"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "conf_room_name": "Pench"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "area": "Mafatlal"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "area": "Andheri"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "Is Personal"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "Meeting"
    }
  ]
]
```

Or Object (easier to reading and understanding):

```
{
  "rooms": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "conf_room_name": "Tadoba"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "conf_room_name": "Melghat"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "conf_room_name": "Ranthambore"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "conf_room_name": "Corbett"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "conf_room_name": "Pench"
    }
  ],
  "areas": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "area": "Mafatlal"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "area": "Andheri"
    }
  ],
  "types": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "type": "Is Personal"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "type": "Meeting"
    }
  ]
}
```

PHP code maybe like below:

```
<?php

$sqlroom = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `room_table`");
$room_rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlroom)) {
  $room_rows[] = $r;
}

$sqlarea = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `area_table`");
$area_rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlarea)) {
  $area_rows[] = $r;
}

$sqltype = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `type_table`");
$type_rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqltype)) {
  $type_rows[] = $r;
}

$result = array();
$result["rooms"] = $room_rows;
$result["areas"] = $area_rows;
$result["types"] = $type_rows;

echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: I am pulling all these values from a mysql server and then using php to encode the json data which gives me the structure of the json array. Is it possible to make this kind of structure using php and mysql?

Comment: Sure, You should control the JSON response as you want.

Comment: {"conf_rooms":[{"id":"1","conf_room_name":"Tadoba"},{"id":"2","conf_room_name":"Melghat"},{"id":"3","conf_room_name":"Ranthambore"},{"id":"4","conf_room_name":"Corbett"},{"id":"5","conf_room_name":"Pench"}],"areas":[{"id":"1","area":"Mafatlal"},{"id":"2","area":"Andheri"}],"types":[{"id":"1","type":"Is Personal"},{"id":"2","type":"Meeting"}]}

Comment: I used your method and got this json data output. Will this work?

Comment: Yes, It is valid JSON. Next time, you should use http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to test/modify/format you JSON

Comment: Can you please tell me how i would access this json data in android to split it into different arraylists. My code is giving still IndexOutofBounds exception?

Comment: Because your code access to an array while the json response as a object. You must change your code, maybe like: JsonObjectRequest JsonObjectRequest(...POST,"...",new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject){        
        JSONArray jRooms = jsonObject.getJSONArray("rooms");

Comment: One of simple way to handle JSON data is using Gson library to convert them into Java Object: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to parse three different types of data: conference rooms, areas (which presumably contain conference rooms?) and some information about either one (although it's not clear which). It therefore doesn't make sense to try and store these in a single array as each element contains a different data structure compared to the other two.

If the `type` is a description of one of the other two objects then it should be compassed within that object, not treated as a separate one. A room doesn't *necessarily* have to sit within an area but it might also make sense to have it there.

You say you are "*pulling all these values from a mysql server and then using php to encode the json data which gives me the structure of the json array*" which implies you do not have direct access to the JSON structure, but you should still have access to the PHP structure. The JSON encoder will use the design of the PHP array / object to structure the JSON so, for this to work you need to create more-or-less matching PHP and Java objects at either end of the serialization process.

For instance:

```
$obj = (object) array
  ('id' => '1', 'area' => 'Mafatlal', 'rooms' => array
    ('id' => '1', 'conf_room_name' => 'Tadoba', 'type' => 'Is Personal'),
    ...
  ('id' => '2', 'area' => 'Andheri', 'rooms' => array...
  );
```

and

```
public class Area {
    private int id;
    private String area;
    private Room[] rooms;

}

public class Room {
    private int id;
    private String conf_room_name;
    private String type;
}
```

Note that, in contrast to the usual Java camel-case naming convention, object variables will usually have to match the incoming JSON variable name (i.e.: `conf_room_name` instead of `confRoomName`).

Comment: Yeah all the three things wiz. area,type and conf_rooms are not related. So should i make different arrays for each of them and make different network calls for each array or should I put them in the same array and parse them in one single network call?

Comment: If they're completely unrelated, consider why you are trying to fetch them all with a single network call. If there is a good reason (like high network latency, for instance), you could put them all in a single object as @Tran Hieu suggested. If they can be treated entirely separately, separate them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add values using for loop.

```
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if(jsonObject.toString.contains("conf_room_name"))
                  stringArray_conf.add(jsonObject.getString("conf_room_name"));
                else if(jsonObject.toString.contains("area"))
                  stringArray_area.add(jsonObject.getString("area"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: i got an error after using your method. This is the logcat.

Comment: 06-13 16:12:17.115 2203-2203/com.example.gandhjee.pantry_order E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.gandhjee.pantry_order, PID: 2203
                                                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gandhjee.pantry_order/com.example.gandhjee.pantry_order.fterLogin}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: try debugging it, check if it enters the loop.